Latching circuit with Un-latching delay using Transistor
I make a latching and un-latching circuit by using transistor & provide it 6 s delay at the time of unlatch by using 555 timer. Before it develop on board I simulate this circuit on PROTEUS and also done bread board testing and got it works fine. But when I develop it on PCB it is easy to latch but create a problem in de-latching.
I attached this circuit below please anyone help to debug this circuit, why it is not Un-latched when I press swich for 6 s and release?


Welcome! If you probe relevant pins on your 555, do you ever reach the threshold level? Your 100 uF may have more leakage current than in your simulation.

Anaya, I would like your thoughts used in making this design.
